# Partially Ordered CFG

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, grammars, partial-order

I'm looking for work about partially ordered context-free grammars. I've found [one paper](http://scholar.google.com/scholar?cluster=2340746033841345494&hl=de&as_sdt=2000&as_vis=1), which seems to simplify the problem too much (in addition to some technical mistakes, as far as I can tell). It defines the language of a  pom-CFG by reduction to a normal context-free grammar, which excludes some (otherwise) possible words from the language, I think.

Thus I'm looking for other work.

**What I mean by partially ordered CFG**

The production rules don't produce linear strings of symbols but partially ordered (multi) sets of symbols. Thus the "words" of the generated language are also partially ordered multi-sets of symbols. For example this:

```
  b-c
 /   \
a     d-a
 \   /
  a--
```

The possible linearizations of this partially ordered word are aabcda, abacda, abcada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The described concept is known as **graph grammars** and dates back into the 1970ies. Searching for this yields a sufficient amount of references. The terms "Graph Transformation" and "Graph Rewriting" are also used. See e.g. [Wikipedia on Graph Rewriting](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Graph_rewriting).

Comment: A graph is not a partially ordered string.

Comment: @reinierpost A graph can be seen as a generalization of a partial order, as a directed graph can be interpreted as a binary relation.

Comment: I know, but here the objects of interest are not graphs, but traces (which can be regarded as equivalence classes of graphs). I like your idea of using graph grammars, but your opening statement is incorrect: rewriting graphs is not the same thing, as you have to make sure to respect the equivalences.

Answer (score -1):

You may be interested in [trace theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_monoid).

There has also been research on (fully) commutative languages.

Not having studied either, I can't give you any more specific references, but Google can.